# How to return service by key

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular and Typescript. I have saw this pattern and don't know what it mean.

```
  constructor(
    private workoutService: WorkoutService,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {}

  private facadeSvc(key: svc) {
    return {
      [svc.AUTH]: this.authService,
      [svc.WORKOUT]: this.workoutService,
    }[key];
  }

  logToConsole(key: any) {
    return this.facadeSvc(key).log();
  }
}

enum svc {
  WORKOUT = 'WORKOUT',
  AUTH = 'AUTH',
}
```

What does `facadeSvc(key: svc)` function do??

In WorkoutService and AuthService had implement `log()` function to log some message to console. Therefore in other component, I only need to inject `FacadeService` and pass in the key, it will automatic call to the correct Service.

Does anyone know what this pattern call??

Thank in advance if anyone can explain to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does facadeSvc(key: svc) function do ?

> This function return the instance of 'authService' or 'workoutService'
> depending on the key provided. Those instances are already available
> to `facadeSvc` method by angular dependency injection (via constructor).
> afterwards, by that
> instance you can access `log()` method of respective service.

Does anyone know what this pattern call??

> It is mix of [Facade pattern](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-javascript-design/9781449334840/ch09s09.html#:%7E:text=Figure%209%2D8.-,Facade%20pattern,to%20the%20public%20for%20use.) and [Chain of
> responsibility.](https://www.dofactory.com/javascript/design-patterns/chain-of-responsibility#:%7E:text=The%20Chain%20of%20Responsibility%20pattern,can%20handle%20a%20particular%20request.)